# Binding events to dynamically added content

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

I have a jquery calendar wich it takes events from a php file wich is feeding json data.
I want to bind a function on every event added to calendar. And I did this:

```
$(this).bind("mouseenter", function(){
        alert("a");
        });
```

It works, but only on second rollover on each event. First time I roll over nothing happens.

Comment: Search for "event delegation".

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can achieve this using JQuery.

```
$(selector).live( evt, function(){} ); // for JQuery 1.7 and less. 

$(document).on( evt, selector, function(){} );
```

**Event Delegation is yet another way you can use to achieve this.**

consider this link => http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Live is however deprecated since jQuery 1.7

Comment: Yes agreed. Let me write a comment on that.